# Обновление данных виджета - кнопка обновления Android Java

Tags: java, android

Создал виджет который при первом запуске берет данные с источника в json формате и показывает в самом виджете. Создал кнопку для обновления данных, установил слушатель, ловлю клик по кнопке, но не могу сделать так чтоб данные обновились, то есть заново отправился запрос и показывал новые данные. Тот же код пишу, выдает ошибку. Может есть метод обновления самого виджета? То есть он обновится и тот запрос который при запуске отправлял заново отправит?

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {


    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    ComponentName watchWidget;

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
    watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, EthWidgetProvider.class);

            //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED));
   // remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED2));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.example_widget_button, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent( context, MainActivity.class), 0) );
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);



    Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, EthWidgetProvider.class);
    updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { id });

    pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, updateIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pIntent);[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
    for(int appId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, EthWidgetProvider.class);











       // remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.timeofday, "TESTING");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

    }

    if (SYNC_CLICKED2.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, EthWidgetProvider.class);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.timeofday, "TESTING2");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

    }
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Распишите вопрос более детально, что вы делаете и что не работает, и покажите ошибку.

Comment: Я увидел код для обновления самого виджета, думал таким образом обновятся данные, Но параметр ID я не знаю чем заполнить. Он у меня высвечивается красным. Я новичек в андроид разработке, по этому пишу сюда и ищу помощи здесь.

Comment: Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, EthWidgetProvider.class);
            updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            updateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { id });

            pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, updateIntent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvPressUpdate, pIntent);

Comment: Весь код в вопрос, а не в комментарий.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Добавил